# Creating an Array that takes user input

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating an array where the user is entering boolean values, and the array will count how many `true`s and `false`s there are will output the number.

For example, if `TorF[] = {true, false, true, true, false}` then it would output `[3,2]` (three `true`s and 2 `false`s).

So far I have this:

```
public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean TorF[] = new boolean[] 

       if (input == False) 
       {
          System.out.println(TorF.length);    
       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.println(TorF.length);
       }
       return TorF;
}
```

Im not too sure if this is right. If someone could help me that would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: `input` is the Scanner not the actual user input.  You need to parse the user input.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` are doing the same thing. That can't be correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's `true` and `false` (you can't use `False` in Java). Also, you just need to count the `true`(s) (because the number of falses is the total count minus the number of trues). And I would use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like,

```
public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
    int trueCount = 0;
    for (boolean b : values) {
        if (b) {
            trueCount++;
        }
    }
    return new int[] { trueCount, values.length - trueCount };
}
```

**or** in Java 8+, something like

```
public static int[] longestStreak(boolean[] values) {
    int trueCount = (int) IntStream.range(0, values.length)
            .filter(i -> values[i]).count();
    return new int[] { trueCount, values.length - trueCount };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 way to do the same:

```
List<Boolean> valuesList = values.asList();
List<Boolean> list2 = valuesList 
    .stream()
    .map(value-> value ? trueCount++ : falseCount++)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());``
```